# db field value +1 hour

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

```
SELECT * FROM (`tabl1` as ap)
WHERE (ap.fromdate BETWEEN "2015-11-20 11:00:00" AND "2015-11-20 12:00:00")
 AND (date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(ap.fromdate)+3600)
      BETWEEN "2015-11-20 11:00:00" AND "2015-11-20 12:00:00")
```

Comment: add some details as well

Comment: [Read this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on a better way to get help

Answer (score 1):

use `DATE_ADD` or `INTERVAL`

```
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

or

```
NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

if your date time coloumn name is `ap.fromdate` use this :-

`ap.fromdate + INTERVAL 1 HOUR`